Mysql/Mariadb Cursor loop is being executed only once returning empty string and exiting
I wanted to do a partial back up of tables good and org and all tables that has foreign keys to these tables. To do that I wrote two procedures. The first one generates insert statements for the data in the given table_name filtered with CONSTRAINT_COL_NAME and values in CONSTRAINT_COL_VALUES. This procedure works as intended when called individually:
Minimal reproducible db:
CREATE TABLE good(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE some_table_1(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    good_id INTEGER REFERENCES good(id)
);


CREATE TABLE some_table_2(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    good_id INTEGER REFERENCES good(id)
);


CREATE TABLE org(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE some_table_3(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    org_id INTEGER REFERENCES org(id)
);


CREATE TABLE some_table_4(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    good_id INTEGER REFERENCES good(id),
    org_id INTEGER REFERENCES org(id)
);

-- Example data:

INSERT INTO good(name) VALUES ('good 1'), ('good 2'), ('good 3');

INSERT INTO org(name) VALUES ('org 1'), ('org 2'), ('org 3');

INSERT INTO some_table_1(name, good_id) VALUES ('some_table_1 1', 1), ('some_table_1 2', 2), ('some_table_1 3', 3);

INSERT INTO some_table_2(name, good_id) VALUES ('some_table_2 1', 1), ('some_table_2 2', 2), ('some_table_2 3', 3);

INSERT INTO some_table_3(name, org_id) VALUES ('some_table_3 1', 1), ('some_table_3 2', 2), ('some_table_3 3', 3);

INSERT INTO some_table_4(name, good_id, org_id) VALUES ('some_table_4 1', 1, 1), ('some_table_4 2', 2, 2), ('some_table_4 3', 3, 3);

Procedure 1:
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GenerateInsertStatements;
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateInsertStatements(IN table_name VARCHAR(64), IN CONSTRAINT_COL_NAME VARCHAR(64), IN CONSTRAINT_COL_VALUES VARCHAR(4096))
BEGIN

    DECLARE col_list TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE col_list_quoted TEXT DEFAULT '';


    -- Construct the comma-separated list of column names
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(cols.COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY cols.ORDINAL_POSITION),
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('QUOTE(', cols.COLUMN_NAME, ')') ORDER BY cols.ORDINAL_POSITION)
    INTO
        col_list,
        col_list_quoted
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as cols
    WHERE
        cols.TABLE_NAME = table_name
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();


    -- Construct the SQL to generate INSERT statements for each row in the table

    SET @sql_ = CONCAT(
    'SELECT CONCAT(''INSERT INTO ', table_name, ' (', col_list, ') VALUES ('', ',
    'CONCAT_WS('','', ', col_list_quoted, '), '')'','''') AS insert_statements
    INTO OUTFILE ''/var/lib/mysql-files/export_data_',table_name, '.txt'' LINES TERMINATED BY ''\n''
    FROM ', table_name, ' ',
    'WHERE ', CONSTRAINT_COL_NAME, ' IN (', CONSTRAINT_COL_VALUES, ');'
    );


    -- Prepare and execute the SQL
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

Calling call GenerateInsertStatements('some_table_1', 'good_id', '2,3'); works as expected and produces a file at the /var/lib/mysql-files/ (Note* Your user must have FILE granted to it. Run as root or user with FILE granted to it - GRANT ALL does not grant FILE!)
Now I want to call for every table that has a foreign key to either good or org; Hence comes the second procedure:

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS export_inserts;
CREATE PROCEDURE export_inserts()
BEGIN

    DECLARE good_ids VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT '2,3';
    DECLARE org_ids VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT '1,2';
    DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(64);

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;


    # Tables that reference good:
    DECLARE cursor_for_good_referees CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('good_id') AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();


    # Tables that reference org:
    DECLARE cursor_for_org_referees CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('org_id') AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();

    -- Handler for when there are no more rows
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET done = 1;

    --
    -- GET ALL GOOD RELATED TABLES
    --

    open cursor_for_good_referees;

    read_loop_1: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_for_good_referees INTO table_name;
        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE read_loop_1;
        END IF;
        SELECT CONCAT('Debug inside loop 1. table_name = ', table_name);
        IF table_name IS NOT NULL THEN
            select 'call';
            call GenerateInsertStatements(table_name, 'good_id', good_ids);
        END IF;
    END LOOP read_loop_1;

    -- Close the cursor
    CLOSE cursor_for_good_referees;

    --
    -- GET ALL ORG RELATED TABLES
    --

    set done = 0;
    open cursor_for_org_referees;

    read_loop_2: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_for_org_referees INTO table_name;
        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE read_loop_2;
        END IF;
        SELECT concat('Debug inside loop 2. table_name = ', table_name);
        IF table_name THEN
            call GenerateInsertStatements(table_name, 'org_id', org_ids);
        END IF;
    END LOOP read_loop_2;
    -- Close the cursor
    CLOSE cursor_for_org_referees;

END $$
DELIMITER ;


call export_inserts();
This is entering the loops only once, table_name is an empty string.
Am I doing something wrong with cursor handler?
The GenerateInsertStatements procedure itself, in theory, could trigger the handler flag, but it needs to be called at least once for that to happen...
What is wrong with the second procedure?

Study this fiddle carefully.

It looks like your read_loop is just doing the same thing as GROUP_CONCAT(). Am I right?

@Barmar Shoot, you are right. I replaced the whole loop thing in the first procedure with group_concat.

@Akina Oh god, after I carefully looked into that fiddle, I noticed that the table_name is highlighted in purple when declared. So table_name is some kind of a keyword? The thing got fixed after I changed the variable name to table_name_. Thanks a lot!

The issue was with the declared table_name variable. In MySQL, TABLE_NAME is a keyword. Hence, using it led to weird behavior. Changing the variable name to table_name_ fixed the issue.
I usually rely on my IDE to highlight all keywords in a special color but for some reason, PyCharm never highlighted it anyhow, making me believe it's ok to use it...
